# Wordpress pagination not returning the same number of posts on pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Here is my code for the pagination. Everything works well, except that after page 2, the number of posts on pages is different. For example, it returns 9 on page 1 and page 2, 8 on page 3, 7 on page 4, 6 on page 5..the number just keeps getting smaller. Is there a reason this is happening? I've tried changing the arguments, but nothing helped so far.

```
    <?php
    if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;
    // Exit if accessed directly
    
    /**
     * @param $posts array
     * @param $every_eighth_full_width boolean
     */
    ?>
    <?if ($posts) :?>
            <div class="row new-post-list">
                <?php 
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $args = array( 'post_type'=> 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish','orderby' => 'post_date',
                'order'   => 'desc', 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'paged' => $paged );
                    $query = new WP_Query($args);
                    $counter = 1;
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                    ?>
                                    <?php
    
                    $hide = get_field('hide_this_blog_post_from_the_main_blog_page', $post->ID);
                    if($hide)
                        continue;
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-12 mb-2 <?= ($every_seventh_full_width && $counter%7 == 0) ? '' : 'col-md-6' ?>">
                        <?php include(locate_template('/templates/posts/new-post-teaser.php')); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $counter++;
                    endwhile;?>
                    <div class="col-12 new-blog-pagination">
                    <?php
                      echo paginate_links(array(
                        'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
                        'prev_text' => '',
                        'next_text' => ''
                      ));
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT: this is how I resolved the issue:

```
            <?php 
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array( 'post_type'=> array('post','guide'), 'post_status' => 'publish','orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order'   => 'desc', 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'paged' => $paged, 'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'       => 'hide_this_blog_post_from_the_main_blog_page',
                    'value'     => '1',
                    'compare'   => '<'
                )
            ) 
        );
                $query = new WP_Query($args);
                $counter = 1;
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                ?>

                <div class="col-12 mb-2 <?= ($every_seventh_full_width && $counter%5 == 0) ? '' : 'col-md-6' ?>">
                    <?php include(locate_template('/templates/posts/new-post-teaser.php')); ?>
                </div>
                <?php
                $counter++;
                endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Well that probably has something to do with how you are _skipping_ posts from the result set there in the output part, based on what `$hide` contains …

Comment: You should prevent those posts that have this specific meta value from being selected in your query in the first place, instead of filtering them out only later. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: @CBroe thanks, it worked when I removed that. I will try to find a solution to exclude those posts

Comment: That what I posted that link for, it explains how to filter based on meta values in the query.

Comment: @CBroe thank you! I managed to resolve my problem, works great now :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe that is because of this piece of code

```
 $hide = get_field('hide_this_blog_post_from_the_main_blog_page', $post->ID);
                if($hide)
                    continue;
```

Do you try to comment this?